# How to encode a URL in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, url, encode

I'm creating a Windows application and I need to pass an encoded URL. But I'm not sure how to encode it in WinForms C#?

Answer (score 37):

If you need to URL-encode data for a querystring, you can use either [Uri.EscapeDataString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx) or, if you don't mind referencing System.Web, [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx):

```
var rawString = @"this & that";
var uriEncoded = Uri.EscapeDataString(rawString);
var httpUtilityEncoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(rawString);
```

They're very similar but can produce subtly different results in the way special characters, like spaces, are encoded:

```
Console.WriteLine(uriEncoded);
// uriEncoded = "this%20%26%20that"

Console.WriteLine(httpUtilityEncoded);
// httpUtilityEncoded = "this+%26+that"
```

Comment: You have to mind about length of the string to URL-encode... if it's larger than 32768 you must use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`.

Answer (score 5):

Try [Uri.EscapeUriString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Did you tried with:

```
var url = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(string);
```

You don't need a dependency on System.Web and you can use it in PCL, I used it in my Xamarin forms project.

Comment: UPDATE:
If you don't have access to HttpUtility class from System.Web that means its replaced with WebUtility. In case if you creating `UriBuilder` class where you append your encoded string with `UriBuilder.AppendFormat`encoded value will be in Builder.Uri.AbsoluteUri field. If you say .ToString() on UriBuilder class, not all characters will be encoded. On this, I preferably think on umlauts, which you can find in the German language for example.